# how to group 1D array consecutive elements in python preferably

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, python-imaging-library, image-segmentation

I have following 1D array:

```
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 16, 249, 142, 149, 189, 135, 141, 146, 294, 3, 2, 0, 3, 3, 6, 2, 3, 4, 21, 22, 138, 95, 86, 110, 72, 89, 79, 138, 14, 18, 18, 18, 12, 15, 21, 22, 11, 20, 26, 90, 62, 128, 94, 117, 81, 81, 137, 7, 13, 14, 6, 10, 8, 11, 10, 13, 21, 18, 140, 69, 147, 110, 112, 88, 100, 197, 9, 20, 5, 6, 5, 4, 7, 10, 21, 32, 42, 56, 41, 156, 95, 112, 81, 93, 152, 14, 19, 9, 12, 20, 18, 14, 21, 18, 18, 14, 91, 47, 43, 63, 41, 45, 43, 85, 15, 16, 14, 10, 11]
```

I can see the pattern where the spikes are. So I want above array grouped as below:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 16], [249, 142, 149, 189, 135, 141, 146, 294], [3, 2, 0, 3, 3, 6, 2, 3, 4, 21, 22], [138, 95, 86, 110, 72, 89, 79, 138]....so on]
```

I tried to use K mean, some combination of mean and std deviation. But none of them are resulting in this kind of grouping. Please help!

Edit:
These data are sum of dark pixel values of gray scaled image along x axes summed up on y axes. Higher range group represent written lines and lower range group represent blank lines. It means, I want to separate written and blank lines on image. So there is a pattern. Written lines will be of same width, that is their group length will be same. Blank lines may have sudden spike because of background noises. But overall, manually,  I can see a pattern of written and blank lines. I want it programmatically.

Answer (score 3):

A simple threshold-based approach will work in this case.

```
x = np.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 16, 249, 142, 149, 189, 135, 141, 146, 294, 3, 2, 
              0, 3, 3, 6, 2, 3, 4, 21, 22, 138, 95, 86, 110, 72, 89, 79, 138, 14, 
              18, 18, 18, 12, 15, 21, 22, 11, 20, 26, 90, 62, 128, 94, 117, 81, 
              81, 137, 7, 13, 14, 6, 10, 8, 11, 10, 13, 21, 18, 140, 69, 147, 
              110, 112, 88, 100, 197, 9, 20, 5, 6, 5, 4, 7, 10, 21, 32, 42, 56, 
              41, 156, 95, 112, 81, 93, 152, 14, 19, 9, 12, 20, 18, 14, 21, 18, 
              18, 14, 91, 47, 43, 63, 41, 45, 43, 85, 15, 16, 14, 10, 11])

mask = x > 30  # Mark values above/below threshold

cuts = np.flatnonzero(np.diff(mask))  # find indices where mask changes
cuts = np.hstack([0, cuts + 1, -1])  # let indices point after the change and add beginning and end of the array.

groups = []
for a, b in zip(cuts[:-1], cuts[1:]):  # iterate over index pairs
    groups.append(x[a:b].tolist())
print(groups)

# [[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 16], [249, 142, 149, 189, 135, 141, 146, 294], [3, 2, 0, 3, 3, 6, 2, 3, 4, 21, 22], [138, 95, 86, 110, 72, 89, 79, 138], [14, 18, 18, 18, 12, 15, 21, 22, 11, 20, 26], [90, 62, 128, 94, 117, 81, 81, 137], [7, 13, 14, 6, 10, 8, 11, 10, 13, 21, 18], [140, 69, 147, 110, 112, 88, 100, 197], [9, 20, 5, 6, 5, 4, 7, 10, 21], [32, 42, 56, 41, 156, 95, 112, 81, 93, 152], [14, 19, 9, 12, 20, 18, 14, 21, 18, 18, 14], [91, 47, 43, 63, 41, 45, 43, 85], [15, 16, 14, 10]]
```

More sophisticated approaches could involve fitting a piecewise constant model or detecting statistical instationarities, but usually it's best to stick with the simplest possible method that works.

Comment: Though it roughly solves the problem. Commenting would have helped me understand, as I am new to it and I will further state what I want exactly. Those array values are sum of dark pixel values on x axes summed up on y axes. Higher value group represent written lines, while lower value group represent blank lines. So, you see, there has to be a pattern. Written lines shall be equal length. 4th last group should have started at 56. To further complicate the matter, Images may have background noises. so I would not know the threshold "30" in advance

Comment: @RahulKumar I exactly answered the question you asked. You should have stated your question more precisely. (For example, there was no way to know how you wanted the 4th last group to be, or what you know in advance and what not.) You can [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42974431/edit) to include that additional information you provided here.